# Landscape Mode - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, landscape

I want my application only works in landscape (horizontal) and put my line is manifest:

```
<activity
   android:name=".HomePageActivity"
   android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>
```

With all this it is horizontal, but if I turn the mobile phone 180 º (horizontal is the same) but the screen does not adpata, stands upside down.

Anyone can help me in this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can try `android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"`, but it's only available for API level 9 (Android 2.3) and newer.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen

Comment: Thanks for the replies

I'm using the version 2.1.
There is solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

What devices do you use for testing?

"Reversal landscape" orientation appears in 2.2.

**Edit**

If you use API >= 9, then look for [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen). You can use `sensorLandscape` orientation.

Comment: Thanks for the replies

I'm using the version 2.1.
There is solution for it?

Comment: No, there isn't official solution. Only possibility is to take information from sensor, and draw revercal views, but I't is not the best idea.